# Magento2 include external resources before local

Tags: magento2, css, external

I have the problem, that my external resources gets loaded after my local resources. So I can't override that styles. I have a custom theme and added a default_head_blocks.xml with the following content:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" src_type="url" />
    <css src="css/test.css" />
</head>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<head>
    ...
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="[...]/css/test.css" />
    <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    ...
</head>
```

How can I first load the external resources in my head section?

Comment: what happens if you switch those lines in the xml? i.e. put the css/tests.css  line before the external source?

Comment: Already tried that. Doesn't change anything. I think the order in the xml file is not relevant. But it's really weird if external resources always gets loaded after local resources...

Comment: @DominikBarann have you resolve this issue?

Comment: @DominikBarann try to write <css src="css/test.css" media="all and (min-width: 1px)"/> and see if it helps. Atleast it helped me to put my internal themes css at the end

Answer (score 0):

This issue because your module load after that module have add `css` file.
You need add the following code in `module.xml`:

```
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
    </sequence>
```

This tags: Load your module before `Magento_Theme` module.

If you installer your module, you need find order load module in path `app/etc/config.php`

Comment: hmm I don't think that's the problem because I load both css files in my custom theme. So the order of that both css files can't be a problem of another module?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue too.
I notice that only if your module is the **first** in `app/etc/config.php` magento reads correctly css sequence in head section.

I think that probably, if another module with css in head section is loaded before your module, then **all modules** css local resources are loaded first and css external resources are loaded all togheter after for last.

Could you try this also in your store?